# Groovy addBatch/executeBatch with autoGenerated keys

Tags: groovy

Has anyone retrieved the auto-generated keys for a database insert while using Groovy SQL's *withBatch* method? I have the following code

```
def Sql target = ...//database connection
target.withBatch { ps ->
    insertableStuff.each { ps.addBatch ( it ) }

    ps.executeBatch()

    def results = ps.getGeneratedKeys()  //what do I do with this? 
}
```

We're using DB2, and I've successfully tested the *getGeneratedKeys* method with a single statement/result set, but once I wrap the process in a batch, I'm not sure what objects I'm dealing with anymore.

According to [IBM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.java/src/tpc/imjcc_tjvbtupd.dita), it is possible to get the results back, but their example is using standard JDBC objects, not the groovy ones. Any ideas?

Comment: What does it show when you print `results` out?

Comment: So I think there are a couple of things messing with me here.1) we're using Apache's DBCP library to manage our connections, and it's wrapping the prepared statement in a DelegatingPreparedStatement class . 2) the SQL class in 'withBatch' doesn't create a statement with the required extra parameter (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String,%20int[])) that will tell JDBC to return the generated values.

Comment: It just prints out the name of the class (DelegatingResultSet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, got it working. I had to hack my way into the Groovy SQL class, and there are some things that I just couldn't do because the methods in the Groovy class were private, so this implementation doesn't support cachedStatements, the isWithinBatch method won't operate correctly in the closure, and there's no access to the number of rows that were updated.

It'd be nice to see some variation of this in the base Groovy code, perhaps with a extension point where you put in your own handler (since you wouldn't want the IBM specific stuff in the base Groovy code), but at least I have a workable solution now.

```
public class SqlWithGeneratedKeys extends Sql {
    public SqlWithGeneratedKeys(Sql parent) {
        super(parent);
    }
    public List<GroovyRowResult> withBatch(String pSql, String [] keys, Closure closure) throws SQLException {
        return this.withBatch(0, pSql, keys, closure);
    }

    public List<GroovyRowResult> withBatch(int batchSize, String pSql, String [] keys, Closure closure) throws SQLException {
        final Connection connection = this.createConnection();
        List<Tuple> indexPropList = null;

        final SqlWithParams preCheck = this.buildSqlWithIndexedProps(pSql);
        BatchingPreparedStatementWrapper psWrapper = null;

        String sql = pSql;
        if (preCheck != null) {
            indexPropList = new ArrayList<Tuple>();
            for (final Object next : preCheck.getParams()) {
                indexPropList.add((Tuple) next);
            }
            sql = preCheck.getSql();
        }

        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        try {
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql, keys);
            this.configure(statement);
            psWrapper = new BatchingPreparedStatementWrapper(statement, indexPropList, batchSize, LOG, this);
            closure.call(psWrapper);
            psWrapper.executeBatch();

            return this.getGeneratedKeys(statement);
        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            LOG.warning("Error during batch execution of '" + sql + "' with message: " + e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        } finally {
            BaseDBServices.closeDBElements(connection, statement, null);
        }
    }

    protected List<GroovyRowResult> getGeneratedKeys(Statement statement) throws SQLException {
        if (statement instanceof DelegatingStatement) {
            return this.getGeneratedKeys(DelegatingStatement.class.cast(statement).getDelegate());

        } else if (statement instanceof DB2PreparedStatement) {
            final ResultSet[] resultSets = DB2PreparedStatement.class.cast(statement).getDBGeneratedKeys();

            final List<GroovyRowResult> keys = new ArrayList<GroovyRowResult>();
            for (final ResultSet results : resultSets) {
                while (results.next()) {
                    keys.add(SqlGroovyMethods.toRowResult(results));
                }
            }
            return keys;
        }
        return Arrays.asList(SqlGroovyMethods.toRowResult(statement.getGeneratedKeys()));
    }
}
```

Calling it is nice and clean.

```
println new SqlWithGeneratedKeys(target).withBatch(statement, ['ISN'] as String[]) { ps ->
    rows.each {
        ps.addBatch(it)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the Groovy SQL stuff out the picture to see if I could get something working, I wanted to make sure that DB2 for z/OS actually supported the function, and was able to get the generated values. I was using [IBM's example](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.java/src/tpc/imjcc_tjvbtupd.dita), however I had to add some extra code to handle for the casting that the IBM example is using.

```
SQL target = ...//get database connection
def preparedStatement = target.connection.prepareStatement(statement, ['ISN'] as String[])
ResultSet[] resultSets = ((DB2PreparedStatement) (ps.getDelegate().getDelegate())).getDBGeneratedKeys()
resultSets.each { ResultSet results ->
    while(results.next()) {
        println results.getInt(1)
    }
}
```

So... that's a little clunky, but it's functional. Unfortunately, by controlling the statement myself, I lost all of the parameter mapping that Groovy normally does for me.

I was looking through the groovy Sql source code and can see where they are explicitly telling the database connection not to handle parameters, so I'm thinking I'll add a new method to Sql.metaClass that can pass in a list of the auto-generated column names or something to make this more palatable.

I also want to see if there's a way to get the getGeneratedKeys method working so that I don't have to do all of that casting. At the very least, a utility method to safely handle the casting for me.

```
try {
    withinBatch = true;
    PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) getAbstractStatement(new CreatePreparedStatementCommand(0), connection, sql);
    configure(statement);
    psWrapper = new BatchingPreparedStatementWrapper(statement, indexPropList, batchSize, LOG, this);
    closure.call(psWrapper);
    return psWrapper.executeBatch();
} catch (SQLException e) {
```

The *createNewPreparedStatement(0)* prevents the creation of a statement which could return the auto-generated keys.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure I wasn't crazy, I re-tried the 'getGeneratedKeys' method again with a statement that I know works and I got no results (see below). I had to recursively spin through the results to find the IBM class. So... not my favorite code, it's pretty brittle, but it's functional. Now I just need to see if I can still use the *withBatch* method somehow, I'll obviously need to override some things.

```
println 'print using getGeneratedKeys'
def results = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys()
while (results.next()) {
    println SqlGroovyMethods.toRowResult(results)
}

println 'print using delegate processing'
println getGeneratedKeys(preparedStatement)

private List getGeneratedKeys(PreparedStatement statement) {
    switch (statement) {
        case DelegatingStatement:
            return getGeneratedKeys(DelegatingStatement.cast(statement).getDelegate())

        case DB2PreparedStatement:
            ResultSet[] resultSets = DB2PreparedStatement.cast(statement).getDBGeneratedKeys()

            List keys = []
            resultSets.each { ResultSet results ->
                while (results.next()) {
                    keys << SqlGroovyMethods.toRowResult(results)
                }
            }
            return keys

        default:
            return [SqlGroovyMethods.toRowResult(statement.getGeneratedKeys())]
    }
}

---- Console Output ----
print using getGeneratedKeys
print using delegate processing
[[KEY:7391], [KEY:7392]]
```